# Create a view with specific conditions

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a view with this structure (org_view) :

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME GUILD_NAME TRIBE_NAME
D1              G1         T1
D1              G1         T2
D1              G2         T3
D2              G3         T4
```

and a mapping table (table_for_mapping) :

```
TRIBE_NAME  SYSTEM
T1          S1
T4          S1
```

What i'm trying to do is to create a new view in which the GUILD_NAME will be replaced with the System if the tribe is found in the mapping table if not the Guild Name will remain.

Ex : new_view :

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME GUILD/SYSTEM    TRIBE_NAME
D1                S1                T1
D1                G1                T2
D1                G2                T3
D2                S2                T4
```

I manage to create a view for this :

```
SELECT org.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
if (org.TRIBE_NAME = map.TRIBE_NAME ,map.SYSTEM,org.GUILD_NAME) as "Guild/System",
org.TRIBE_NAME
from org_view org left join table_for_mapping map 
on org.TRIBE_NAME = map.TRIBE_NAME
```

The problem is when one SYSTEM is mapped directly under one GUILD.
One GUILD can have multiple TRIBES under it, but if a SYSTEM is mapped under the GUILD directly then all the tribes should be mapped to the SYSTEM.

```
Ex : GUILD_NAME       TRIBE_NAME
     GUILD_EUROPE     GUILD_EUROPE
     GUILD_EUROPE     TRIBE_WEST
     GUILD_EUROPE     TRIBE_NORTH
     GUILD_EUROPE     TRIBE_EAST
```

So in this case if the SYSTEM is mapped to TRIBE_NAME = GUILD_EUROPE :

```
TRIBE_NAME    SYSTEM
GUILD_EUROPE  SYSTEM_1
```

Then in the new view :

```
 GUILD/SYSTEM    TRIBE_NAME
    SYSTEM_1        GUILD_EUROPE
    SYSTEM_1        TRIBE_EAST
    SYSTEM_1        TRIBE_WEST
    SYSTEM_1        TRIBE_NORTH
```

I know that the if in the view i created needs to be removed for this case ,but for the moment i didn't find any solution so that's why i'm asking for help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the code below can solve your problem

```
SELECT
    org.DEPARTMENT_NAME ,
    org.GUILD_NAME ,
    coalesce(map2.`SYSTEM` , map.`SYSTEM` , org.GUILD_NAME ) "Guild/System"
from
    org_view org
left join table_for_mapping map on
    org.TRIBE_NAME = map.TRIBE_NAME
left join table_for_mapping map2 on
    org.GUILD_NAME = map2.TRIBE_NAME
;
```

The idea is to left join `org_view` with `table_for_mapping` twice, and then leverage the `coalesce` function to determine the value of new column.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but unfortunately that query doesn't do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

`select org.DEPARTMENT_NAME, if (temp.SYSTEM is not null ,temp.SYSTEM,org.GUILD_NAME) as "Guild/System", org.TRIBE_NAME from org_view org left join  (select org.GUILD_NAME,tfm.SYSTEM from org_view org inner join table_for_mapping tfm on org.TRIBE_NAME = tfm.TRIBE_NAME ) temp on temp.GUILD_NAME = org.GUILD_NAME order by org.DEPARTMENT_NAME ASC`

above Query

1. Check SYSTEM is mapped under the GUILD directly.
2. If match found It should be mapped to the SYSTEM.

Comment: Hello , that didn't work ,it only show the GULD_NAME even if i have SYSTEM mapped to tribe.

Comment: @rzss275 please check now i have update the query. I will work now.Thank you.

Comment: i tried again ,still is not doing what i want , the problem is that it does not shown the SYSTEM for the tribes if  the SYSTEM it's mapped under the GUILD directly it only show for the GUILD itself.

Comment: @rzss275 Thanks for better explanation. Please try with above updated query. If it pass i will explain the query for better understanding.

Comment: Now it works fine when mapping at GUILD level ,but if tried to map only one or two tribes from the GUILD to a SYSTEM then all the tribes from that GUILD will be mapped to the same SYSTEM which is not good ,only the 2 i mapped should appear under that SYSTEM the rest of them should be under the GUILD NAME